# A transient final field used as a lock is null

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception, final, transient

The following code throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
import java.io.*;

public class NullFinalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.useLock();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(buffer).writeObject(foo);
        foo = (Foo) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray())).readObject();
        foo.useLock();
    }

    public static class Foo implements Serializable {
        private final String lockUsed = "lock used";
        private transient final Object lock = new Object();
        public void useLock() {
            System.out.println("About to synchronize");
            synchronized (lock) { // <- NullPointerException here on 2nd call
                System.out.println(lockUsed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
About to synchronize
lock used
About to synchronize
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullFinalTest$Foo.useLock(NullFinalTest.java:18)
    at NullFinalTest.main(NullFinalTest.java:10)
```

How can `lock` possibly be null?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Self-answering questions is not only allowed, but also encouraged.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`A transient final field used as a lock is null`

**Here are few facts about the transient variable:**

**-** Transient keyword when used on an instance variable, will **prevent that instance variable to be serialized.**

**-** On De-serialization, the transient variable get to their **Default values**.....

**Eg:**

- Object Reference Variable to `null`
- int to `0`
- boolean to `false,` etc.......

So thats the reason you are getting a `NullPointerException`, when deserializing it...

Answer (score 4):

Any field that is declared `transient` is not serialized. Moreover, according to [this blog post](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/can-transient-variables-be-declared-as-final-or-static/0), field values are not even initialized to the values that would be set by a default constructor. This creates a challenge when a `transient` field is `final`.

According to [the Serializable javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), deserialization can be controlled by implementing the following method:

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

I came up with the following solution, based on [this excellent StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/1237044):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class NullFinalTestFixed {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.useLock();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(buffer).writeObject(foo);
        foo = (Foo) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray())).readObject();
        foo.useLock();
    }

    public static class Foo implements Serializable {
        private final String lockUsed = "lock used";
        private transient final Object lock = new Object();
        public void useLock() {
            System.out.println("About to synchronize");
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(lockUsed);
            }
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            in.defaultReadObject();
            initLocks(this, "lock");
        }
    }

    public static void initLocks(Object obj, String... lockFields) {
        for (String lockField: lockFields) {
            try {
                Field lock = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(lockField);
                setFinalFieldValue(obj, lock, new Object());
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setFinalFieldValue(Object obj, Field field, Object value) {
        Exception ex;
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiers.setAccessible(true);
            modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
            field.set(obj, value);
            return;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            ex = e;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            ex = e;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Running it results in the following output (no `NullPointerException`):

```
About to synchronize
lock used
About to synchronize
lock used
```

Comment: The blog post you cite doesn't say anything at all about default values, let alone what you claim above. It doesn't even make sense: what *else* would they be initialized to? Your code solution is excessively complex as well: you don't need reflection for this.

Comment: The blog post says, "an instance member field declared as final could also be transient, but if so, you would face a problem a little bit difficult to solve... when you deserialize the object you would have to initialize the field manually, [but the compiler complains because it is final]... Now, when you deserialize the class your logger will be a null object, since it was transient." This is the problem my answer solves. Without reflection, how do *you* propose that we set the value of a `final` field? Your comment is excessively vitriolic as well: you don't need snark for this.

Comment: The blog didn't say what you said it said. Period. My comment also doesn't say what you claim: the remainder of it can be reduced to the word 'excessive', which is hardly 'vitriolic' or 'snarky'. This baffles me.

Comment: Sorry, it sounds like we're having a misunderstanding around the overloaded word, "default." In my post above, I was referring to values set in the class definition, i.e., those set before construction.

Comment: Note that the Android implementation of `Serializable` lacks the `readObject()` method, hence this solution will work only on JRE (and fully compatible implementations) but will not compile on Android.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out before, the declaration below does not work as one might expect:

```
transient final Object foo = new Object()
```

The `transient` keyword will prevent the member from being serialized. **Initialization with a default value is not honored during deserialization,** therefore `foo` will be `null` after deserialization.

The `final` keyword will prevent you from modifiying the member once it has been set. This means you're stuck with `null` forever on a deserialized instance.

In any case you will need to drop the `final` keyword. This will sacrifice immutability, but should not usually be an issue for `private` members.

Then you have two options:

### Option 1: Override `readObject()`

```
transient Object foo = new Object();

@Override
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    foo = new Object();
}
```

When creating a new instance, `foo` will be initialized to its default value. When deserializing, your custom `readObject()` method will take care of that.

This will work on JRE but not on Android, as Android's implementation of `Serializable` lacks the `readObject()` method.

### Option 2: Lazy initialization

Declaration:

```
transient Object foo;
```

On access:

```
if (foo == null)
    foo = new Object();
doStuff(foo);
```

You would have to do this wherever in your code you access `foo`, which may be more work and more error-prone than the first option, but it will work on JRE and Android alike.